# Validação de formulário não funciona com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse código ajax que faz uma requisição de uma página php

```
$(document).on('click', '#reg-discagem input[type="submit"]', function(e){

 $("#form-content_discagem").html('<div class="spinner"></div>');
           e.preventDefault(); 
var form = $('#reg-discagem');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'EnviarPedidoChamada.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form.serialize() 
            })
            .done(function(data){
                $('#form-content_discagem').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('#form-content_discagem').fadeIn('slow').html(data);


                });
            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');    
            });
});
```

Preciso colocar uma validação dos campos do formulário, mais quando coloco o código jquery abaixo junto com o código acima, a validação não funciona, o que eu poderia fazer para funcionar? Usei o **jquery.validate.min.js**

```
    $(document).on('click', '#reg-discagem input[type="submit"]', function(e){

 $("#form-content_discagem").html('<div class="spinner"></div>');
           e.preventDefault(); 
var form = $('#reg-discagem');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://3mind.com.br/EnviarPedidoChamada.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form.serialize() 
            })
            .done(function(data){
                $('#form-content_discagem').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('#form-content_discagem').fadeIn('slow').html(data);


                });
            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');    
            });
});

$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#reg-discagem').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                field1: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                field2: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }
        });

    });
```

meu formulário

```
<form action="" id="reg-discagem" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group ligacao">
        <label for="inputEmail">Seu Nome</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Seu nome">
    </div>
<div class="form-group ligacao telefone">

<div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">

                <div class="col-md-4"><label for="inputPassword">Seu País</label><br>




            <select name="countryCode" id="paises" style="clear:both;">
        <option data-countryCode="BR" value="55" selected>Brasil (+55)</option>
    <optgroup label="Other countries">
<option value="93">AFEGANISTAO</option>
<option value="27">AFRICA DOUL</option>
<option value="1">ALASCA</option>
<option value="355">ALBANIA</option>
<option value="49">ALEMANHA</option>
<option value="376">ANDORRA</option>
<option value="244">ANGOLA</option>
<option value="1">ANGUILLA</option>
<option value="599">ANT.HOLANDESAS</option>
<option value="1">ANTIGUA</option>
<option value="966">ARABIAAUDITA</option>
<option value="213">ARGELIA</option>
<option value="54">ARGENTINA</option>
<option value="374">ARMENIA</option>
<option value="297">ARUBA</option>
<option value="247">ASCENSAO ILHAS</option>
<option value="61">AUSTRALIA</option>
<option value="43">AUSTRIA</option>
<option value="994">AZERBAIJAO</option>
<option value="1">BAHAMAS</option>
<option value="880">BANGLADESH</option>
<option value="1">BARBADOS</option>
<option value="973">BAREIN</option>
<option value="375">BELARUS</option>
<option value="32">BELGICA</option>
<option value="501">BELIZE</option>
<option value="229">BENIN</option>
<option value="1">BERMUDAS</option>
<option value="591">BOLIVIA</option>
<option value="387">BOSNIA E HERZEGOVINA</option>
<option value="267">BOTSUANA</option>
<option value="55" selected>BRASIL</option>
<option value="673">BRUNEI</option>
<option value="359">BULGARIA</option>
<option value="226">BURKINA FASO</option>
<option value="257">BURUNDI</option>
<option value="975">BUTAO</option>
<option value="238">CABO VERDE</option>
<option value="237">CAMAROES</option>
<option value="855">CAMPUCHEA</option>
<option value="1">CANADA</option>
<option value="7">CASAQUISTAO</option>
<option value="974">CATAR</option>
<option value="1">CAYMAN ILHAS</option>
<option value="235">CHADE</option>
<option value="56">CHILE</option>
<option value="86">CHINA</option>
<option value="357">CHIPRE</option>
<option value="65">CINGAPURA</option>
<option value="57">COLOMBIA</option>
<option value="269">COMORES</option>
<option value="242">CONGO</option>
<option value="682">COOK ILHAS</option>
<option value="850">COREIA DOORTE</option>
<option value="82">COREIA DOUL</option>
<option value="225">COSTA DO MARFIM</option>
<option value="506">COSTA RICA</option>
<option value="385">CROACIA</option>
<option value="53">CUBA</option>
<option value="246">DIEGO GARCIA</option>
<option value="45">DINAMARCA</option>
<option value="253">DJIBUTI</option>
<option value="1">DOMINICA</option>
<option value="1">DOMINICANA REP</option>
<option value="20">EGITO</option>
<option value="503">ELALVADOR</option>
<option value="971">EMIRADOS A. UNIDOS</option>
<option value="593">EQUADOR</option>
<option value="291">ERITREA</option>
<option value="386">ESLOVENIA</option>
<option value="34">ESPANHA</option>
<option value="1">ESTADOS UNIDOS</option>
<option value="372">ESTONIA</option>
<option value="251">ETIOPIA</option>
<option value="298">FAROE ILHAS</option>
<option value="679">FIJI</option>
<option value="63">FILIPINAS</option>
<option value="358">FINLANDIA</option>
<option value="886">FORMOSA</option>
<option value="33">FRANCA</option>
<option value="241">GABAO</option>
<option value="220">GAMBIA</option>
<option value="233">GANA</option>
<option value="995">GEORGIA</option>
<option value="350">GIBRALTAR</option>
<option value="1">GRANADA</option>
<option value="30">GRECIA</option>
<option value="299">GROENLANDIA</option>
<option value="590">GUADALUPE</option>
<option value="1">GUAM</option>
<option value="502">GUATEMALA</option>
<option value="592">GUIANA</option>
<option value="594">GUIANA FRANCESA</option>
<option value="224">GUINE</option>
<option value="240">GUINE EQUATORIAL</option>
<option value="245">GUINE-BISSAU</option>
<option value="509">HAITI</option>
<option value="1">HAVAI</option>
<option value="31">HOLANDA</option>
<option value="504">HONDURAS</option>
<option value="852">HONG KONG</option>
<option value="36">HUNGRIA</option>
<option value="967">IEMEN REP.</option>
<option value="91">INDIA</option>
<option value="62">INDONESIA</option>
<option value="98">IRA</option>
<option value="964">IRAQUE</option>
<option value="353">IRLANDA</option>
<option value="354">ISLANDIA</option>
<option value="972">ISRAEL</option>
<option value="39">ITALIA</option>
<option value="1">JAMAICA</option>
<option value="81">JAPAO</option>
<option value="962">JORDANIA</option>
<option value="686">KIRIBATI</option>
<option value="965">KUWEIT</option>
<option value="856">LAOS</option>
<option value="266">LESOTO</option>
<option value="371">LETONIA</option>
<option value="961">LIBANO</option>
<option value="231">LIBERIA</option>
<option value="218">LIBIA</option>
<option value="423">LIECHTENSTEIN</option>
<option value="370">LITUANIA</option>
<option value="352">LUXEMBURGO</option>
<option value="853">MACAU</option>
<option value="389">MACEDONIA</option>
<option value="261">MADAGASCAR</option>
<option value="60">MALASIA</option>
<option value="265">MALAVI</option>
<option value="960">MALDIVAS</option>
<option value="223">MALI</option>
<option value="356">MALTA</option>
<option value="500">MALVINAS ILHAS</option>
<option value="1">MARIANASORTE ISL.</option>
<option value="212">MARROCOS</option>
<option value="692">MARSHALL ILHAS</option>
<option value="596">MARTINICA</option>
<option value="230">MAURICIO</option>
<option value="222">MAURITANIA</option>
<option value="269">MAYOTTE(ILHAS)</option>
<option value="52">MEXICO</option>
<option value="691">MICRONESIA</option>
<option value="838">MIDWAY ILHAS</option>
<option value="258">MOCAMBIQUE</option>
<option value="373">MOLDOVA</option>
<option value="976">MONGOLIA</option>
<option value="382">MONTENEGRO</option>
<option value="1">MONTSERRAT</option>
<option value="264">NAMIBIA</option>
<option value="674">NAURU</option>
<option value="977">NEPAL</option>
<option value="505">NICARAGUA</option>
<option value="227">NIGER</option>
<option value="234">NIGERIA</option>
<option value="683">NIUE</option>
<option value="672">NORFOLK ILHA</option>
<option value="47">NORUEGA</option>
<option value="687">NOVA CALEDONIA</option>
<option value="64">NOVA ZELANDIA</option>
<option value="968">OMA</option>
<option value="680">PALAU</option>
<option value="970">PALESTINA</option>
<option value="507">PANAMA</option>
<option value="675">PAPUAOVA GUINE</option>
<option value="92">PAQUISTAO</option>
<option value="595">PARAGUAI</option>
<option value="51">PERU</option>
<option value="48">POLONIA</option>
<option value="1">PORTO RICO</option>
<option value="351">PORTUGAL</option>
<option value="377">PRINCIPADO MONACO</option>
<option value="254">QUENIA</option>
<option value="996">QUIRGUIZIA</option>
<option value="44">REINO UNIDO</option>
<option value="236">REP.CENTRO AFRICANA</option>
<option value="421">REP.ESLOVAQUIA</option>
<option value="420">REP.TCHECA</option>
<option value="262">REUNIAO ILHAS</option>
<option value="854">RODRIGUES ILHAS</option>
<option value="40">ROMENIA</option>
<option value="250">RUANDA</option>
<option value="7">RUSSIA</option>
<option value="1">S.KITTS &NEVIS</option>
<option value="1">S.VICENTE ILHAS</option>
<option value="833">SAARA ESPANHOL</option>
<option value="677">SALOMAO ILHAS</option>
<option value="685">SAMOA</option>
<option value="684">SAMOA AMERICANA</option>
<option value="1">SANTA LUCIA</option>
<option value="378">SAO MARINO</option>
<option value="239">SAO TOME E PRINCIPE</option>
<option value="221">SENEGAL</option>
<option value="232">SERRA LEOA</option>
<option value="381">SÃƒï¿½RVIA</option>
<option value="248">SEYCHELLES</option>
<option value="963">SIRIA</option>
<option value="252">SOMALIA</option>
<option value="94">SRI-LANKA</option>
<option value="508">ST.PIERRE E MIQUELON</option>
<option value="290">STA HELENA ILHAS</option>
<option value="268">SUAZILANDIA</option>
<option value="249">SUDAO</option>
<option value="46">SUECIA</option>
<option value="41">SUICA</option>
<option value="597">SURINAME</option>
<option value="992">TADJIQUISTAO</option>
<option value="66">TAILANDIA</option>
<option value="689">TAITI</option>
<option value="255">TANZANIA</option>
<option value="672">TERRIT.EXT.AUSTRALIA</option>
<option value="670">TIMOR LESTE</option>
<option value="228">TOGO</option>
<option value="676">TONGA</option>
<option value="690">TOQUELAU</option>
<option value="1">TRINIDAD E TOBAGO</option>
<option value="216">TUNISIA</option>
<option value="993">TURCOMENIA</option>
<option value="1">TURKS E CAICOS ILHAS</option>
<option value="90">TURQUIA</option>
<option value="688">TUVALU</option>
<option value="380">UCRANIA</option>
<option value="256">UGANDA</option>
<option value="95">UNIAO DE MYANMAR</option>
<option value="598">URUGUAI</option>
<option value="998">UZBEQUISTAO</option>
<option value="678">VANUATU</option>
<option value="58">VENEZUELA</option>
<option value="84">VIETNA</option>
<option value="1">VIRGENS A. ILHAS</option>
<option value="1">VIRGENS B.ILHAS</option>
<option value="839">WAKE ILHAS</option>
<option value="681">WALLIS E FUTUNA</option>
<option value="243">ZAIRE</option>
<option value="260">ZAMBIA</option>
<option value="259">ZANZIBAR</option>
<option value="263">ZIMBABUE</option>   </optgroup>
</select></div>

<div class="col-md-8">        <label for="telefonephone">Seu telefone </label><br>
<input type="text" id="telefonephone" name="telefonephone" class="form-control telefonephone" placeholder="(DD) XXXXX-XXXX"></div></div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group ligacao" style="clear:both; margin-top:-20px;">
        <label for="inputPassword">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Seu Email">
    </div>
    <div id="form-content_discagem" style="clear:both;">

    <input type="submit"  class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" style="background-color: #f05d2d;border: 1px solid #f05d2d;font-size: 20px;color: #fff;font-family: lato;padding: 20px;border-radius: 6px;margin-bottom: 3px;margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none !important;" value="Receber ligação">
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: qual erro aparece no console do navegador?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve informar dentro das `rules` qual campo deve ser validado.

Troque de `field` para o `name` do elemento que deseja validar, exemplo:

```
email: {required: true,email: true}
```

Caso você queria verificar se o seu formulário é valido no momento da chamada Ajax, você pode utilizar o [.valid()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/):

```
if($('#reg-discagem').valid()){
  //Ajax
}
```

Segue um exemplo com seu código:

```js
$('#reg-discagem').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        nome: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { 
        console.log("Valido");
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="reg-discagem" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate>

  <div class="form-group ligacao">
      <label for="nome">Seu Nome</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Seu nome">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ligacao telefone">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="paises">Seu País</label>
        <select name="countryCode" id="paises" style="clear:both;">
          <option data-countryCode="BR" value="55" selected>Brasil (+55)</option>
          <optgroup label="Other countries">
            <option value="93">AFEGANISTAO</option>
            <option value="591">BOLIVIA</option>
            <option value="387">BOSNIA E HERZEGOVINA</option>
            <option value="267">BOTSUANA</option>
            <option value="55" selected>BRASIL</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <label for="telefonephone">Seu telefone </label>
        <input type="text" id="telefonephone" name="telefonephone" class="form-control telefonephone" placeholder="(DD) XXXXX-XXXX">            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group ligacao" style="clear:both; margin-top:-20px;">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Seu Email">
    </div>
    <div id="form-content_discagem" style="clear:both;">
      <input type="submit" id="btn"  class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" style="background-color: #f05d2d;border: 1px solid #f05d2d;font-size: 20px;color: #fff;font-family: lato;padding: 20px;border-radius: 6px;margin-bottom: 3px;margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none !important;" value="Receber ligação">
    </div>
</form>
```